# Angular: How to click on modal button when user hits Enter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I have several [Angular UI Modals](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#/modal). Every modal has a **Cancel** button and an "Action" button (which can be **Create**, **Delete**, etc).

I use the [`ui-keyup` directive](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-keypress) from Angular UI to identify when user pressed buttons.

I would like to click the "Action" button when user hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

How could I achieve that?

Here is where I got to so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/n6dgiE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/icKazZ?p=preview

So, I just made sure that `createIt()` was available on the `ui-event` (by moving the controller up to `<body>`) and just triggered it directly.

Now lets say this isn't feasible (there are too many layers between the body tag and the `createIt()` function). What you **COULD** do is put some sort of global-handler function or service on `$rootScope` and then pass the triggering through. However communication down scopes, or across controllers is outside the explicit scope of this question **:-)**

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. In your example: __1.__ When the "Delete Something" dialog is opened and you hit Enter, `createIt()` is called rather than `deleteIt()`. __2.__ Only when you hit Enter `createIt()` or `deleteIt()` should be called. __3.__ If none of the modals is opened, and you hit Enter, nothing should happen.